# ISSET checking in php not working

Tags: php, forms, post

I have this php code. When I try to manually navigate to this php script without submitting, the error for not setting the post is not showing. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['submit']));
 {
    $productname=$_POST['productname'];
    //$conn string will go here 
    $result=$conn->query("INSERT INTO products(pname)VALUES('$productname')");
    if($result)
    {
       echo "<font color=\"green\">";
       echo("Successfully Inserted new Products");
       echo"</font>!";
    }
    else
     {
       echo("error");
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your else corresponds to inside if:  if($result) {...} else { error }

Comment: What do you see? An empty page?

Comment: @Jim i see the green success message always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
// semicolon removed
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $productname=$_POST['productname'];
    //$conn string will go here 
    $result=$conn->query("INSERT INTO products(pname)VALUES('$productname')");
    if($result) {
        echo "<font color=\"green\">";
        echo("Successfully Inserted new Products");
        echo"</font>!";
    }
} else { // else placed correctly ...
    echo("error");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

With indentation, we can see that your else condition is inside the "`if (!isset($_POST['submit']))`"
Also, I think you don't need the semicolon after `if (!isset($_POST['submit']))`

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])); // <== This semicolon shouldn't exist
{
    $productname=$_POST['productname'];
    //$conn string will go here 
    $result=$conn->query("INSERT INTO products(pname)VALUES('$productname')");
    if($result)
    {
        echo "<font color=\"green\">";
        echo("Successfully Inserted new Products");
        echo"</font>!";
    }
    else
    {
        echo("error");
    }
} // <== Need an "else" here
?>
```

Here is how the code should be

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $productname=$_POST['productname'];
    //$conn string will go here 
    $result=$conn->query("INSERT INTO products(pname)VALUES('$productname')");
    if($result)
    {
        echo "<font color=\"green\">";
        echo("Successfully Inserted new Products");
        echo"</font>!";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<font color=\"red\">";
        echo("Error when inserting");
        echo"</font>!";
    }
} 
else
{
    echo "error";
}
?>
```

**EDIT :**

you need to do "`if (isset($_POST['submit']))`" instead of "`if (!isset($_POST['submit']))`" to test if the form was submitted. I fixed the code above.

Comment: Ah! You need `if( isset() )` instead of `if ( !isset() )`